# To substitute a string with sed command

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to substitute below string with a space and save it to a file.

```
*wrap*_trig[0]
```

I tried below sed cmd but it not working. What is going wrong over here.

```
sed -i 's/*wrap\*_trig[0\]/ /g' file.txt
```

Comment: `[` needs to be escaped too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\*wrap\*_trig\[0\]/X/g' file
```

Remember `*` and `[...]` are metacharacters on the LHS of a substitution command and if literal must be escaped/quoted either by a prefixing a `\` or by surrounding the character by `[` and `]`. An `*` and `]` need not be quoted when there is no character preceding the first or no opening `[` with the second.

Here are some more solutions:

```
sed 's/[*]wrap[*]_trig[[]0[]]/ /g' file
```

or

```
sed 's/*wrap\*_trig\[0]/ /g' file
```